# qt prevent qdialog/window from moving with mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt4.8

**Env**

- OS X 10.6.8 ... and later, Windows XP ... and later.
- Qt 4.7 (has to be, legacy issues, OS X 10.6.8 must be supported, Qt5 won't do it)

**Problem**

I have opened a second window in my application. It behaves as I want it to, *except* that if the MainWindow in the application moves, so does this window. That behavior is unwanted (actually more like "toxic and user-unfriendly").

The Qt docs say not to call move() from within moveEvent(), and anyway moveEvent() only shows up after window has stopped moving, not even *while* moving, which would, even if I did use it successfully, result in second window moving and snapping back, which would be pretty awful.

I thought to try overriding move() and not calling QDialog::move(), but that didn't work, it seems it cannot be overridden; rfview window still follows mainwindow around.

Perhaps I am opening the window wrong:

```
void MainWindow::xrfview()
{
    ttrfview = new rfview(this);
    uiframePlot = ttrfview->ui->framePlot;
    ttrfview->show();
    ttrfview->raise();
}
```

Or perhaps I have defined the window wrong:

```
class rfview: public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit rfview(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~rfview();
}
```

Or both?

Basically, if the user drags/re-positions MainWindow, I do *not* want the `rfview` window to follow.

Comment: trt with: ttrfview = new rfview();

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, that worked under OS X, my dev environment. Please make it an answer and I will give the 'ol checkmark. Thank you for a very fast solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ttrfview = new rfview(this)` to `ttrfview = new rfview()`